# Attempting to program quadratic formula?

Tags: java, quadratic

I am new to Java - one of my first projects is to build a calculator.

Attempted to program a quadratic equation; and although I got no errors, I got the wrong answer.

```
void quadratic() {
    if((b*b-4*a*c) < 0){
        System.out.println("The answer is imaginary.");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println(
             "The two roots x values of the quadratic function "
             + a + "x^2 + " + b + "x + " + c + " are "
             + ((-b) + (Math.sqrt((b*b)-(4*a*c))/(2*a))) + " and "
             + ((-b) - (Math.sqrt((b*b)-(4*a*c))/(2*a)))
        );
    }
}
```

If I substitute `a=1, b=4, c=4`, I get -4 and -4.

If I substitute `a=1, b=1, c=-12`, I get 2.5 and -4.5.

It may just be a mathematical error, but I think the formula's correct.

Comment: Style tip: don't spell it all out, introduce some intermediate variables. The root of the discriminant, for one thing, just begs to be calculated separately and reused.

Answer (score 1):

No, the forumlas are not quite right. You are dividing the wrong thing by `2*a`.

My advice would be to factor out the discriminant calculation, and get rid of the redundant parentheses. This will make it easier to get the code right:

```
void quadratic() {
    double discriminant = b*b-4*a*c;
    if(discriminant < 0) {
        System.out.println("The answer is imaginary.");
    } else {
        System.out.println(
                "The two roots x values of the quadratic function "
                + a + "x^2 + " + b + "x + " + c + " are "
                + (-b + Math.sqrt(discriminant)) / (2*a) + " and "
                + (-b - Math.sqrt(discriminant)) / (2*a)
                );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing parentheses, should be

```
(((-b) + (Math.sqrt((b*b)-(4*a*c)))/(2*a))) + " and " + (((-b) - (Math.sqrt((b*b)-(4*a*c)))/(2*a))))
```

You need to divide the whole thing by 2a.

Comment: ah got it ((-b + (Math.sqrt(b*b-4*a*c)))/2*a)

Comment: Nope you switched /(2*a) with /2*a which is not the same thing.

Comment: FWIW, if you have a syntax-highlighting editor, it should be able to show you matching parenthesis, which helps a bit. Better still, name some of those repeated sub-expressions as variables, and simplify the tangle of parentheses.